# np.where returning empty index for list of tuples

Tags: python, numpy

Can anyone tell me how to fix the following code? np.where should return index 0.

```
import numpy as np
listoftups=[("a", "b"), ("n"), ("c","d","e"), ("f", "g")]
np.where(listoftups==("a", "b"))
```

Comment: Have a look at what `listoftups==("a", "b")` evaluates to.

Comment: Why is that? How can I modify this to return the index where the tuple occurs...

Comment: In Python the argument of a function (like `np.where`) is evaluated before it is passed to the function.  If that argument evaluates to a simple `False`, then `where` will return an empty index - there aren't any True values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you are trying to find the index of the tuple. Here is a solution which doesn't require numpy.

```
listoftups=[("a", "b"), ("n"), ("c","d","e"), ("f", "g")]
search_tuple = ("a", "b")
print(listoftups.index(search_tuple))
```

Will return 0

```
search_tuple = ("f", "g")
print(listoftups.index(search_tuple))
```

Will return 3

Answer (score 5):

```
np.where(('a','b') in listoftups)
```

What you have in your code returns false

```
>>> listoftups==("a", "b")
False
```

Where as,

```
>>> ('a','b') in listoftups
True
```

Comment: This will not work in general, since `listoftups` is a python list if `("a", "b")` is in the list then the result will be true, and the result will be index 0 no matter what tuple you search for. See @watchdog101 answer for a more general solution.

Comment: np.where returns an array index (array([0], dtype=int64),) for the match.  how to you get the tuple values for the mask

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to force numpy to do what you want:

```
listoftups=[("a", "b"), ("n"), ("c","d","e"), ("f", "g")]
```

1. `where` operates on boolean arrays, a comparison like a==b will create a boolean array if a or b is a numpy array but not if both are native python objects. Let's also create an example with two occurrences of the search tuple.

.

```
arroftups = np.array(listoftups)
twice = np.concatenate(2*[listoftups])
```

2. one minor challenge is preventing numpy to attempt broadcasting when it sees the two element test tuple. We can do that by encapsulating it in a 0d array

.

```
probe = np.empty((),object)
probe[()] = "a", "b"
```

3. now we are good to go:

.

```
np.where(arroftups==probe)
# (array([0]),)
np.where(twice==probe)
# (array([0, 4]),)
```

Note if you are sure there is exactly one occurrence of the test tuple, then @Watchdog101's solution is probably better. But it will not work in the general case.